# Qual a diferença entre uma Classe Mediadora (Interposer Class) e uma Classe de Ajuda (Helper Class) no Delphi?

Tags: delphi, orientação-a-objetos

Sempre trabalhei mais com classes interposer. Sei que é melhor criar componentes, mas às vezes é mais rápido fazer um ajuste pontual usando uma interposer. Novas versões do Delphi possuem o conceito de classes helper e achei parecido com as interposers, inclusive parecem mais simples de implementar, mas será que existe alguma vantagem em se usar classes interposers em detrimento das classes helper?

Comment: Bacana sua pergunta, não sei te dizer qual a diferença, mas eu costumo usar o Interposer para classes mais complexas ou com visual, por exemplo, Criar uma nova regra no `TfrxReport` com botões na tela de preview. Já os Class/Record Helper, para métodos mais simples Ex: Criar um `SaveToFile` para um String. Não sei se é o correto, mas estou ansioso para ver as respostas.

Comment: É, eu também gostaria de ver alguma resposta a respeito disso. Vamos aguardar :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Classe Mediadora**

Uma **Classe Mediadora** (`Interposer Class`) é uma classe que, hierarquicamente falando, se posiciona entre uma `classe ancestral` (*da qual ela deriva*) e a declaração de um *objeto do tipo desta classe*. *Possui como principal característica o fato de ter o mesmo nome da sua classe ancestral*, o que torna sua aplicação simplificada em sistemas que já possuem objetos declarados do tipo dessa classe.

Para que uma CM (**Classe Mediadora**) funcione é imprescindível que a declaração da mesma esteja entre a declaração da *classe original (**classe ancestral**)* e a declara do objeto do tipo da CM. A *interposer Class* pode estar mesmo em uma `unit` separada, desde que esta `unit` esteja posicionada APÓS a `unit` que contém a *classe ancestral* na cláusula `uses` e desde que a cláusula `uses` em questão esteja ANTES da declaração dos objetos do tipo da CM.

**Implementando a Classe Mediadora**

Vamos agora incrementar a classe mediadora para que ela faça o que queremos. A implementação não difere do que seria feito se tivéssemos feito um componente de forma correta, por exemplo. O legal da CM é que ela não tem nada de especial, a não ser o seu posicionamento específico dentro da hierarquia. Primeiramente vamos fazer com que o nosso TEdit aceite apenas números. O Isso é bem manjado. Segue abaixo o código:

```
01  unit UFormPrincipal;
02
03  interface
04
05  uses
06    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, 
07    System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
08    Vcl.StdCtrls;
09   
10  type
11     TEdit = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit)
12     protected
13       procedure KeyPress(var PKey: Char); override;
14       procedure Loaded; override;
15     public
16     end;
17
18  TFormPrincipal = class(TForm)
19    EDIT: TEdit;
20    private
21    { Private declarations }
22    public
23    { Public declarations }
24    end;
25
26  var
27  FormPrincipal: TFormPrincipal;
28
29  implementation
30 
31  {$R *.dfm}
32
33  { TEdit }
34
35  procedure TEdit.KeyPress(var PKey: Char);
36  begin
37  inherited;
38    if not (PKey in ['0'..'9',#8,'-']) then
39      PKey := #0;
40  end;
41
42  procedure TEdit.Loaded;
43  begin
44  inherited;
45    Text := '';
46  end;
47  
48  end.
```

Acehi nesse [Site](http://www.zettaomnis.net.br/portal/a2d-mei/articles-a2d-mei/111-classes-mediadoras-interposer.html):

---

- **Class Helper**

No Delphi, *Class Helper* é um recurso que permite *adicionar métodos e modificar comportamentos de componentes em tempo de execução, sem a necessidade de herdar a classe ou utilizar recursos de composição*, fazendo parecer que a classe contém o novo comportamento desde sua criação.

Outro diferencial é que *Class Helpers* não se aplicam somente a componentes. Eles também permitem modificar classes de domínio criadas pelo desenvolvedor, adicionar métodos a estruturas do tipo record e tipos primitivos (introduzidos a partir da versão XE3). Nesse último caso, no entanto, não é possível adicionar propriedades.

Na código abaixo é apresentada uma `unit` que implementa um `Class Helper` para adicionar ao componente `TEdit` a capacidade de validar seu texto, definindo se ele representa um CPF ou CNPJ.

```
01  unit UnitEditDocumento;
02     
03  interface
04  
05  uses
06     vcl.stdCtrls, SysUtils;
07  
08  type
09     TEditDocumento = class helper for TEdit
10     private
11        function TextoSemSinais: string;
12     public
13        function isPessoaFisica: boolean;
14        function isPessoaJuridica: boolean;
15  end;
16  
17  implementation
18  
19  uses
20     UnitUtils;
21  
22  { TEditDocumento }
23  
24  function TEditDocumento.TextoSemSinais: string;
25  var
26    //Retorna o texto sem caracteres especiais
27  end;
28  
29  function TEditDocumento.isPessoaFisica: boolean;
30  begin
31     result := length(TextoSemSinais) = 11;
32  end;
33  
34  function TEditDocumento.isPessoaJuridica: boolean;
35  begin
36     result := length(TextoSemSinais) = 14;
37  end;
38  end.
```

1. Linha 9: sintaxe para declaração do Class Helper. Essa instrução
   indica que está sendo criado um `Class Helper` (que é uma classe) para
   modificar o componente `TEdit`;
2. Linhas 10 a 15: declaração dos métodos da classe;
3. Linhas 24 a 37: implementação dos métodos da classe.

Perceba que toda a estrutura do `Class Helper` é a mesma de uma classe convencional, alterando apenas a forma de declaração.

***Como utilizar***
Sempre que for necessário utilizar um componente que possua o novo comportamento, basta adicionar o nome da unit em que está declarado o `Class Helper` na seção `uses`. A partir disso, será possível acessar os novos métodos adicionados, conforme mostra a Listagem 2.

```
01  procedure TForm5.Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
02  begin
03     if Edit1.isPessoaFisica then
04        Label1.Caption:='Documento Pessoa Física'
05     else
06     begin
07        if Edit1.isPessoaJuridica then
08           Label1.Caption:='Documento Pessoa Jurídica'
09        else
10        begin
11           Label2.Caption:='Documento Inválido';
12           exit;
13        end;
14     end;
15  end;
```

No Código acima utilizando os métodos adicionados pelo `Class Helper`
Nesse código, estamos trabalhando com o evento `OnExit` do componente `TEdit`, e nas linhas 3 e 7 utilizamos os novos métodos adicionados pelo `Class Helper`.

***Modificando métodos existentes***
Além de adicionar novos métodos, o `Class Helper` permite que modifiquemos os métodos já existentes em um componente. No código abaixo apresentamos um exemplo de modificação do método `Clear` para uma situação especial em um formulário onde os componentes `TEdit` que aceitam texto recebem a string “xxxx” ao serem limpos, e os que aceitam apenas números recebem o texto “0000”. Esse comportamento pode ser necessário em algumas telas do sistema, a partir das quais temos, por exemplo, que imprimir o conteúdo em impressoras matriciais. Nesses casos, em planilhas de formulário contínuo, os campos não podem aparecer em branco para não descaracterizar a impressão.

```
01  Unit UnitEditMatricial;
02  ...
03  type
04     TEditDocumento = class helper for TEdit
05     public
06        procedure Clear;
07     end;
08  
09  ...
10  
11  procedure TEditDocumento.Clear;
12  begin
13     if NumbersOnly then
14        Text:= StringOfChar('0',MaxLength)
15     else
16        Text:=StringOfChar('X',MaxLength);
17  end;
```

**Class Helper* para modificar um método já existente no `TEdit`*

Agora, quando adicionarmos a referência a essa `unit` na seção `uses` e acionarmos o método `Clear` de um `TEdit`, esse novo método será executado, ao invés do procedimento padrão que elimina todo o texto do campo.

Retirado do Site [devmedia.com.br](https://www.devmedia.com.br/class-helpers-no-delphi-modificando-componentes-da-vcl/36773)

Comment: Cara, valeu mesmo pela resposta. Muito completa e detalhada! Valeu muito mais, porque você usou parte do que eu escrevi no meu site pra responder a minha própria pergunta e isso me deixa muito feliz, já que eu sei que você achou meu conteúdo interessante!

Fiz esta pergunta em outubro de 2016 e publiquei o artigo sobre interposers em novembro. A pergunta surgiu porque eu sempre usei interposers e nunca usava helpers, aliás, a pergunta surgiu justamente enquanto eu escrevia o artigo! Muito obrigado pela resposta

Comment: valeu! Vi sua pergunta e resolvi procurar para responder passei quase duas horas para entender como funciona... mais valeu a pena.